# Custom title for MultiplePieChart

Tags: java, charts, label, jfreechart

Need to create in JFreeChart multiplePieChart with custom charts label. In documentation example title for charts create automatically. 
Documentation example:

```
package demo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.MultiplePiePlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.util.TableOrder;

public class MultiplePieChartDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame
{

    public MultiplePieChartDemo1(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 380));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset()
    {
        double ad[][] = {
            {
                3D, 4D, 3D, 5D
            }, {
                5D, 7D, 6D, 8D
            }, {
                5D, 7D, (0.0D / 0.0D), 3D
            }, {
                1.0D, 2D, 3D, 4D
            }, {
                2D, 3D, 2D, 3D
            }
        };
        CategoryDataset categorydataset = DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset("Region ", "Sales/Q", ad);
        return categorydataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset categorydataset)
    {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createMultiplePieChart("Multiple Pie Chart", categorydataset, TableOrder.BY_ROW, true, true, false);
        MultiplePiePlot multiplepieplot = (MultiplePiePlot)jfreechart.getPlot();
        JFreeChart jfreechart1 = multiplepieplot.getPieChart();
        PiePlot pieplot = (PiePlot)jfreechart1.getPlot();
        pieplot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0}"));
        pieplot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", 0, 8));
        return jfreechart;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel()
    {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MultiplePieChartDemo1 multiplepiechartdemo1 = new MultiplePieChartDemo1("JFreeChart: MultiplePieChartDemo1.java");
        multiplepiechartdemo1.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(multiplepiechartdemo1);
        multiplepiechartdemo1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But in my case i have allocation of internet traffic by tariffs with name (for example "Super", "Student", "VIP"). That is no good for me option when JFreeChart generate "tariff 1", "tariff 2".... How to make custom labels for pie charts?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116931).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `DatasetUtilities#createCategoryDataset` is designed for demos rather than production code.  Try this:

```java
private static CategoryDataset createDataset()
{

    DefaultCategoryDataset categorydataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    categorydataset.addValue(3D, "Super", "Sales/Q1");
    categorydataset.addValue(4D, "Super", "Sales/Q2");
    categorydataset.addValue(3D, "Super", "Sales/Q3");
    categorydataset.addValue(5D, "Super", "Sales/Q4");

    categorydataset.addValue(5D, "Student", "Sales/Q1");
    categorydataset.addValue(7D, "Student", "Sales/Q2");
    categorydataset.addValue(6D, "Student", "Sales/Q3");
    categorydataset.addValue(8D, "Student", "Sales/Q4");

    categorydataset.addValue(5D, "VIP", "Sales/Q1");
    categorydataset.addValue(7D, "VIP", "Sales/Q2");
    categorydataset.addValue(0D, "VIP", "Sales/Q3");
    categorydataset.addValue(3D, "VIP", "Sales/Q4");

    return categorydataset;
}
```